# Downloading Apache for Windows

Tags: apache

I'm teaching myself PHP and I have no idea which version of Apache to download. Should I just select httpd-2.4.10.tar.bz2 and try to install it?

Comment: 2.4 Is the current stable release, is also what many many many Linux based web boxes are running

Comment: Ah I found it. I was looking for the windows installer found here. http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/win32/